# Identify correct Locators forCapturing Objects

Tags: javascript, html, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am new to building automation using Protractor.

Can you please help me in identifying which locator I can use to capture a element which is a text box field in my protractor tests?

Below is the HTML I captured from Firebug:

```
input class="input ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" ti-autosize="" ti-bind-attrs="{type: options.type, placeholder: options.placeholder, tabindex: options.tabindex, spellcheck: options.spellcheck}" ng-class="{'invalid-tag': newTag.invalid}" ng-trim="false" ng-paste="eventHandlers.input.paste($event)" ng-blur="eventHandlers.input.blur($event)" ng-focus="eventHandlers.input.focus($event)" ng-keydown="eventHandlers.input.keydown($event)" ng-change="eventHandlers.input.change(newTag.text)" ng-model="newTag.text" placeholder="20 numbers remaining" style="width: 135px;" spellcheck="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to find the element, for example:

- [`by.model`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model):

  ```
  element(by.model('newTag.text'))
  ```
- [`by.css`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css):

  ```
  element(by.css('input.input'))
  ```